# Mixed decimal input with siunitx

Tags: siunitx, decimal-number

Does siunitx take mixed decimal inputs like 0,004319689898685966 and 0.004319689898685966?
It looks like it, but is it intended to work like this?

I am using Python for my calculations with a "." decimal symbol and manually type with a "," decimal symbol.

Image:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=-,
            detect-all,
            decimalsymbol=comma,
            round-mode=places,
            round-precision=4,
            range-units=single,
            per-mode=fraction,}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \SI{0,004319689898685966}{\meter \squared}
\item \SI{0.004319689898685966}{\meter \squared}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is intentional. There are settings for what it should look for and what it should normalise the output to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since input data for `\SI` might come from various sources, one can use various styles for it; in particular a decimal period or a decimal comma in the input is converted to use a marker that's set with `output-decimal-marker`.

The key `decimalcomma` is still allowed for it, but it issues a warning

```latex
Package siunitx Warning: Version 1 option 'decimalsymbol' detected.
```

There are various options to comply with different input styles, but at the end the output is always normalized according to the chosen options regarding the decimal marker, the group separations and so on.

Options can be set globally (but respecting TeX groups) with `\sisetup` or locally with an optional argument to `\SI`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  range-phrase=-,
  detect-all,
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=4,
  range-units=single,
  per-mode=fraction,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \SI{0,004319689898685966}{\meter \squared}
\item \SI{0.004319689898685966}{\meter \squared}
\item \SI[output-decimal-marker=.]{0.004319689898685966}{\meter \squared}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker=\ensuremath{{\cdot}}}
\item \SI{0.004319689898685966}{\meter \squared}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `siunitx` package distinguishes between

- `input-decimal-markers`, with default `,.`, i.e., both comma and period (aka "full stop") are interpreted as decimal marker, and
- `output-decimal-marker`, which defaults to `.` (period).

A compilable example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num{0.333} and \num{0,333}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}} % change the default

\num{0.333} and \num{0,333}
\end{document}
```